# angular2-jwt.d.ts gives "Cannot find module '@angular/http" error

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular2 "2.0.0-beta.17".

My package.json is as follows

```
"dependencies": {
        "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "zone.js": "0.6.12",    
        "angular2-jwt":"0.1.15",
        "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.0.1"    
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "angular-cli": "0.0.*",
        "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
        "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
        "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
        "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.1.3",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
        "karma": "0.13.19",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
        "karma-coverage": "^0.5.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
        "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
        "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
        "null-loader": "git+https://github.com/webpack/null-loader.git",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
        "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
        "protractor": "^3.1.1",
        "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
        "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
        "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
        "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
        "tslint": "^3.4.0",
        "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
        "typescript": "^1.8.0",
        "typings": "^0.7.12",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
        "webpack": "^1.12.13",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
        "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
        "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
        "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
        "tsconfig-lint": "^0.7.0"
      }
```

But after building my project I get following error:

> ERROR in
>   C:\Users\akhilesh.kumar\Desktop\ang17\node_modules\angular2-jwt\angular2-jwt.d.ts
>   (1,61): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.
>
> ERROR in ./~/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js Module not found: Error:
>   Cannot resolve module '@angular/core' in
>   C:\Users\akhilesh.kumar\Desktop\ang17\node_modules\angular2-jwt  @
>   ./~/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js 11:13-37
>
> ERROR in ./~/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js Module not found: Error:
>   Cannot resolve module '@angular/http' in
>   C:\Users\akhilesh.kumar\Desktop\ang17\node_modules\angular2-jwt  @
>   ./~/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js 12:13-37

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@angular/http` is only available from RC versions of Angular2. Before it was `angular2/http`.

Since the angular2-jwt library requires the `@angular/http` module, you need to upgrade your application to a RC version of Angular2.

For this you can update your `package.json` file and execute the command: `npm install`:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular": "2.0.0-rc.1",
   (...)
}
```

Comment: Can I downgrade my angular2-jwt somewhere when it uses angular2/http

Comment: So should I have to put it in only my package.json or I need to change my project as well? If I'm going to use RC Version.

Comment: No changing the `package.json` file and run `npm install` is enough. I updated my answer...

Comment: This is not a correct solution anymore. The correct solution is " npm install angular2-jwt --save "

Answer (score 11):

you need to add dependencies of angular2-jwt:

```
npm install angular2-jwt --save
```

Comment: this works,
the accepted answer seems not working!

Comment: My project didn't want to update first, '--force' helped

Answer (score 2):

**try this:**

```
npm install @angular/http@latest
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Answer (score 1):

As Thierry said "**@angular/...** supported later version of angular then "^2.0.0-rc.0"

So I changed The dependencies as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.1.15",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

and changed imports as follows

```
import {enableProdMode, provide} from "@angular/core";
import {ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {Http,HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import { AuthConfig, AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
```

It worked.

Answer (score 1):

It might be problem with your npm, Try to install the latest version of npm.

Linux:

```
npm install -g npm@lts
```

Answer (score 1):

Providers have Http included by default, and in order to use Http in your app you will need to add the HttpModule to your app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Angular 11 what error I faced was, I was installing `npm install angular2-jwt` but for Angular 11 this wont work.

So we need to first remove the above package using `npm uninstall angular2-jwt`

Install `npm install @auth0/angular-jwt` and then we can perform Token Authentication, if one is also stuck on Token Authentication

For further documentation one can visit https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Answer (score 0):

This is my angular and node config :-

> Angular CLI: 7.1.4 ,
>   Node: 10.6.0 ,
>   Angular: 7.1.4

and I fixed this

> angular2-jwt.d.ts gives “Cannot find module '@angular/http” error

using

```js
npm i @angular/http@^2.0.0||^4.0.0  --save
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular 7 we use `HttpClient` instead of Http

You can import it like this

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```